# How can I place this div next to the other one?

Tags: html, css

I was wanting to make a website, just to see if I like doing it and how it would turn out, but I can't seem to get this part done. I want the "informatie" div to be next to the "vertmenu" div and make it fill up the white part and I want the "vertmenu" div to extend till the "voetregel" div. I have no idea how to get this done and I have already tried changing the width and height to percentages, changing the positions to absolute/relative and adding a float property, but I couldn't make it how I wanted it to be. So my question in short, how can I make the "informatie" div next to the "vertmenu" div and make it fill up the white part and get the "vertmenu" div to extend till the "voetregel" div.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

#hormenu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
  line-height:50px;
  font-size:100%;
}

#vertmenu {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.3);
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  top:15%;
  width:15%;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:3px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#informatie {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.3);
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:85%;
  left: calc(15% + 6px);
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:3px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#voetregel {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0, 0.3);
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  top:auto;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin-left:10px
}

a.hormenu_item {
  margin: 10px;
  transition: color 0.3s, text-shadow 0.3s, text-decoration-line 0.3s, font 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:link.hormenu_item {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited.hormenu_item {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover.hormenu_item {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px gold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#informatie h1, #vertmenu h1, #voetregel h2 {
  color:#FF0000;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div id="hormenu">
   <a href="" class="hormenu_item">Home</a>
   <a href="" class="hormenu_item">Biografie</a>
   <a href="" class="hormenu_item">Features</a>
   <a href="" class="hormenu_item">Contact</a>
 </div>

 <div id="vertmenu">
 <h1>vertmenu</h1>
  </div>

 <div id="informatie">
 <h1>informatie</h1>
  </div>

 <div id="voetregel">
 <h2>voetregel</h2>
  </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: CSS Flex-Box could help. See: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply `float:left;` css in #vertmenu and #informatie

and dont use `position:fixed;` in #voetregel use `clear:both;` it will clear the float effect of above 2 div tags

`position:fixed;` is used for creating menubar in web site so that even with the scrolling that menubar stays at same place

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: inline-block` to make them next to each other. Remove `position:fixed` from `#voetregel` too.

```css
#vertmenu {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.3);
  width:15%;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#informatie {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.3);
  width:85%;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#voetregel {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0, 0.3);
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

#vertmenu,
#informatie {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#informatie h1, 
#vertmenu h1, 
#voetregel h2 {
  color:#FF0000;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="vertmenu">
 <h1>vertmenu</h1>
  </div>

 <div id="informatie">
 <h1>informatie</h1>
  </div>

 <div id="voetregel">
 <h2>voetregel</h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer, because without the clear:both; in #voetregel, the green stuff was floating: http://prntscr.com/fw3230

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx Yeah, no worries!